# SQL Server query performance on longer date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, date-range

I am trying to query a table which has a column that stores the transaction data that is in XML. My filer option is actually 1 of the node in my XML data. So below is my query

```
SELECT eRefNo, eCreationDate, eData 
FROM TableA
WHERE CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/Header/ExportToGMACS/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)) = 'True' 
AND ((CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting1/KindOfPayment[@MPText]')AS nvarchar(1000)) = 'Claims') 
OR (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting1/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) >= convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103) AND (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting1/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) <= convert(datetime, '31/07/2011', 103))) 
OR (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting2/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) >= convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103) AND (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting2/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) <= convert(datetime, '31/07/2011', 103))) 
OR (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting3/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) >= convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103) AND (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting3/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) <= convert(datetime, '31/07/2011', 103))) 
OR (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting4/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) >= convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103) AND (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting4/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) <= convert(datetime, '31/07/2011', 103))) 
OR (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting5/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) >= convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103) AND (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting5/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) <= convert(datetime, '31/07/2011', 103))) 
OR (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting6/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) >= convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103) AND (CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml ).query('Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting6/PaymentDate/text()')AS nvarchar(1000)), 103) <= convert(datetime, '31/07/2011', 103))))
```

When I set my date range to search from `01/Jan/2011` to `31/Jul/2011`, it takes FASTER compared to when my date range is from `01/Jul/2011` to `31/Jul/2011`.

I couldn't understand this peculiar performance issue. All along I thought a wider date range will take longer to execute as it has more rows to return?

Any experts out there please advise.

Thanks
Johnson

---

I have tried and anyway it doesnt help much in my query by reducing a single cast.

my main impt question is the wider date range filter taking shorter time than a shorter date range filter.

any idea what is the reason for it?

I am using MS SQL Server 2005

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: You **do know** that you could simplify this - right??  `CAST(CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml).query('Test/Header/ExportToGMACS/text()') AS nvarchar(1000))` could more easily be written as: `CAST(CAST(eData AS text) AS xml).value('(Test/Header/ExportToGMACS)[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)')` - at least saves you one CAST

Comment: What h*** datatype is `eData` that you have to cast it as `text` first (which I'd **NEVER** do - `Text` is deprecated - use `varchar(max)` instead!!) and then cast it as `xml`......

Comment: I have tried and anyway it doesnt help much in my query by reducing a single cast.

my main impt question is the wider date range filter taking shorter time than a shorter date range filter.

any idea what is the reason for it?

I am using MS SQL Server 2005

Comment: You can remove all cast from this query but one. Add a cross apply like this `CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(eData AS xml)) as T(X)` and then `T.X.value` to extract the values you need. Something like this for the interval check `T.X.value('(Test/PaymentAccountingDetail/PaymentAccounting1/PaymentDate)[1]', 'datetime') between '20110101' and '20110731'`.

Answer (score 0):

This query is not optimized with an index so there has to be a table scan to figure out what rows should be returned. That means that every row in the table will be checked against the where clause.

Your technique with `cast` and `query` is rather expensive so my *guess* (I have not tested this) is that the query optimizer shortcuts the `or` conditions so that when you get a hit it will not continue to check the consecutive conditions. Which means that you save time by expanding the date-range because fewer rows will be checked against **all** `or` conditions.